# Using nested objects with Flow in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a question regarding nested state objects with flow …

So let’s say I want a conditional parameter `close` inside an object in the state in my React component.

```
class Appearance extends React.Component {
  state: {
    house: {
      open: number,
      close?:number,
    },
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const house = {
      open: 0,
    };
    if (props.door) {
      house.close = 0;
    }
    this.state = {
      house,
    };
  }
```

This seems to give me an error `close. Property not found in object literal`
Am I doing something wrong or can I do this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a sealed object literal with `const house = { open: 0 };`

Check [Sealed object types](https://zhenyong.github.io/flowtype/docs/objects.html#sealed-object-types) from the flow documentation.

Try

```
let house = { };
house.open = 0;
if ( props.door ) {
  house.close = 0;
}
```

or... you can use `Object.assign` and keep it as a sealed object

```
const house = Object.assign({}, 
  {open: 0},
  props.door ? {close: 0} : null
);
```

Note: Flow will not allow you to use

```
const house = Object.assign({}, 
  {open: 0},
  props.door && {close: 0}
);
```

because `props.door && {close: 0}` becomes a boolean and Flow does not support that